# Regular Expression, search for a string before a "certain string"

Tags: regex, batch-file

I'm trying to run a regular expression in a batch file that will search a text file for a string. However, the only unique identifier for my string comes after the string, but on the same line.

I'm searching the file for the registry key of an item.

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{RegistryKey}   DisplayName    REG_SZ    Node.js
```

The only string that is unique however is the Node.js part, so I need to use regedit to look for the `RegistryKey` before the `DisplayName    REG_SZ    Node.js` text. If anyone has any advice for this, that would be helpful.

Currently to select the string I'm using

```
/(\{.*\})(\n\s*.)(DisplayName    REG_SZ    Node.js)
```

And I can select the string. Is there a way to access the capture group 1 in batch???? so that I can have the registryKey that I need?

Edit Via request:

In batch I'm trying something like this currently

```
@ECHO off 
::reg query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{6BA2207A-7E42-434C-8DD4-A2FFC1D9EA68}" > nul
REG Query HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\ /V "DisplayName" /S >> testSearch.txt
::type "testName"
for /F "tokens=*" %%A in (testSearch.txt) do echo %%A
findstr /r /x "/(\{.*\})(\n\s*.)(DisplayName    REG_SZ    Node.js)" testSearch.txt >> saveLine.txt
pause
```

My problem now is I just want to save control group 1 (being the {registryKey})
I guess I could use the saved text file and the parse it in javascript to just return the registry key, I've been using a lot of Javascript and batch intertwined via node.

Comment: Show your actual code, not just your regular expression.

Comment: yes, show it please. I'm curious to see `batch` doing REGEX...

Comment: [findstr](https://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html) has only a very limited subset of REGEX. No way for it to do even remotely what you want. (and it's the _only_ command in `cmd` that supports at least a minimum of REGEX).

Comment: Thanks Stephen, I'll probably write the file with Batch, and then pass it into a JS file to perform the regex then, thank you!

Comment: `for /F "tokens=2 delims={}" %%a in (saveLine.txt) do echo Registry key = %%a`

Answer (score 0):

the `batch` way of parsing a string is a `for` loop. To extract a portion (or some portions) of the string, use proper tokens and delimiters. To find the correct line inside the textfile, use `find` or `findstr`:

```
@echo off
setlocal 
for /f "tokens=1-3 delims={}" %%a in ('type b.txt^|find "DisplayName    REG_SZ    Node.js"') do (
  echo %%a
  echo %%b
  echo %%c
)
```

If I understand you correctly, you need the first token `%%a` only.